# Not getting value from query string

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, query-string, jakarta-mail

In my application there is a registration form, after submission, it will be mailed to admin for accept/deny the registration.

In mail sending time a unique key is appending with `Accept button`. After clicking this button an `actionListener` will be fired in controller, and there I want to read unique key value from query String but I am getting null, though the URL `http://localhost:8080/BridgeFront/app/AproveReq.xhtml?activityId=LFGP13005` contains the query String parameter. Have I done anything wrong? If anybody know please let me know. 
One thing I want to say in my project I am using spring framework.

in web.xml I have writen this for filtering:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInView</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

code of `AproveReq.xhtml` is given below:

```
<h:form>
<p:commandButton value="Aprove" action="#{aproveDeny.xyz}"/>
<p:commandButton value="Deny"/>
</h:form>
```

controller is below:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "aproveDeny")
@RequestScoped
public class AproveDeny{

@ManagedProperty("#{param.activityId}")

private String activityId;

public void xyz(){
    System.out.println("-------+++"+getActivityId());
}

public String getActivityId() {
    return activityId;
}

public void setActivityId(String activityId) {
    this.activityId = activityId;
}}
```

Set the mail body(MimeMessage) in this way:

```
MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
mimeMessageHelper.setTo("xxxxxx.xxxx@gmail.com");
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
text.append("<html>");
text.append("<body>");
text.append("<a href="+URL+"?activityId="+ActivityId+">Accept Or Deny request.."+"</a>");
text.append("</body>");
text.append("</html>");
mimeMessageHelper.setText(text.toString(), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use your managed bean with view scoped. First of all change it to the **request scoped** then inject your parameter to a variable in class.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "activityEntryController")
@RequestScoped
public class ActivityEntryController{

@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.activityId}")
private String activityId;

public void aproveActivityEntryReq(ActionEvent event){
  // make your work
}  
}
```

if you have more than one parameters in your url, you shoul add one more variable to class and annotate it with **ManagedProperty**, for example if you want to send also an email in url parameter

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.email}")
private String email;
```

Comment: thanks @oko for reply, I don't understand `@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.activityId}")` without only this, I tried my bean's scope in requestScoped it is not working, `request.getQueryString()` returns null.

Comment: ManagedProperty is a special annotation, it is defining a variable that takes url parameter and injects directly into it. When your admin opens the page, this activityId will be injected to the key variable. And ManagedProperty only works with **requestScoped** beans.

Comment: automatically param `activityId` will be injected into variable `key`??

Comment: yes it would be, JSF has many good specialities. Why don't you give a try ?

Comment: If there are more than one parameter in queryString what will hapen?

Comment: use one more variable with managed property annotation. let me edit my answer.

Comment: in your scenario, if i am not wrong, admin is opening a page url which is sent to him. Then, in page he will accept or deny. So requestScoped bean and managedProperty will work true, but lets change something.

use action attribute in button instead of your actionListener, you do not have to handle action events. then add "ajax=false" to the your command button.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested take action ,place of actionListener, and set ajax attribute `false`, till now it gives null value.

Comment: it is hard to maintain problem with your comments, but i am assuming that you clearly defined getters and setters for your variables. print out your activityId in action method, is it still giving null ? (i.e. System.out.print(getActivityId); or System.out.print(this.activityId); )

Comment: yes I placed getters and setters for `activityId` but I am not understanding how it prints null, though the queryString is displaying in url.

Comment: @Diganta please edit and post your tries (xhmtls and beans) on question,  It is difficult to understand here.

Comment: thanks for helping me @oko: I have edited question. I have not set `ajax=false` though I checked it and I got null value and if `ajax=false` is set then after button click queryString is disapearing.

Comment: @Diganta where is value definition in managedproperty ? correct this like in my example, and use "ajax=false" :

@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.activityId}")
private String activityId;

Comment: After set `ajax=false` and `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.activityId}")` I am till getting null? After button click queryString is disapearing.

Comment: @Diganta this is strange, even it is still giving null if you do not specify "ajax=false", right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28797/discussion-between-oko-and-diganta)

Answer (score 0):

Adding metadata to your AproveReq.xhtml page will pass activityId to your managed bean

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="activityId" value="#{aproveDeny.activityId}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

metadata tag should be at the start of the page i.e before the head tag.

Comment: no it also returns null. I think problem is generated else where. But I don,t know where I have done mistake. Thnks for reply.

Comment: hmm I have copied your code jsf page & controller and the only change I did is added metadata tag and hit the url passing activityId and it worked.

Comment: from where you set the query String value?

Comment: I passed it in url http://localhost:8080/myjsfapp/faces/getparam.xhtml?activityId=LFGP13005